# Can I use "intend" or "intention" for a planned development?

Tags: word-usage

According to the dictionary, "to intend" means "to have as a plan". So I guess I can use **intend** or **intention** for a planned development such as the one shown in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327143/can-we-use-will-to-describe-future-plans)?

> All factories are **intended** to be removed for housing.

> There is **intention** to remove all factories for housing.

Comment: Yes, you can, especially when a subject is named. _The council intends to demolish the factories._

Comment: You wouldn't use intention like that. "There is an intention to...", "There is the intention to...", or "The intention is to..." Or "There is intent to..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intend), intend means "to have as a plan or purpose".

In my opinion, it is mainly used in the active voice for a plan (where the person or entity with the plan is the subject), and the passive voice form for purpose (where the patient is the thing that has a purpose).

> The council intends to demolish the factories and replace them with housing - *active voice*
> The life jackets are intended for emergency use only - *passive voice*.

[Intention](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intention) is used only for a plan, and the correct usage is like this:

> The intention is to remove all factories and replace them with housing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That is to say, it is incorrect to say all factories are intended to be removed for housing, but is correct to say the area where factories are is intended for housing?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was _incorrect_, but it is much less idiomatic than the other suggested versions.

Comment: "Removed for housing" makes it sound like the factories are going to be disassembled and the materials will be used to build houses. It's the land that's to be used for housing, not the factory buildings. You could alternatively say "removed to make way for housing".

Comment: Thanks both of you for your responses. That is to say, it isn't 'intend' that causes the problem. The problem is "removed for housing". If I use 'replaced by housing', then it will be no problem? **All factories are intended to be replaced by housing.**

Comment: @newbieforever as I said in my answer, the passive voice form is usually used to express purpose rather than planning. So "All factories are intended to be replaced by housing" implies that the purpose of the factories is to be replaced by housing. To get the planning meaning, you would say "The councils is planning to replace the factories with housing"